# Can I connect to Linux VM from Windows Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: windows-server-2008, ubuntu, remote-desktop

I am able to connect to windows VM using Remote Desktop connection.
BUt i am not able to connect to linux VM.

However if i use VNC software , then i can connect.

Can i do some setting in RDC so that i can connect to linux as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [xrdp](http://xrdp.sourceforge.net/).  I used it for a bit while transitioning one client from linux to windows

Comment: I installed xrdp in Ubuntu . I am able to coonect using RDC but the whole screen looks blank with mouse in ceenter

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Linux uses rdesktop to connect via RDP but this doesn't include a server which means the connection can only go from Linux to Windows. You could try [Xrdp](http://xrdp.sourceforge.net/) which is meant to extend rdesktop to allow connections from Windows to Linux.